# Mongo automatic POJO maps object with null values \

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to get documents from MongoDB and map them to my object. Inserting works well. Retrieving collection also seems have everything in it. But I can't figure out why deserializing object doesn't work as intented. I'm new to Java and I could've simply forget about something, didn't understand documentation properly. But from what I've read it should work properly.

I have this code

```
[...]

CodecProvider pojoCodecProvider = PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build();
CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), fromProviders(pojoCodecProvider));

_mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientURI);
_mongoDataBase = _mongoClient.getDatabase(dbName).withCodecRegistry(pojoCodecRegistry);

[...]
```

And in a fuction another function I get the collection and cast it to an ArrayList:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = _mongoDataBase.getCollection(collectionName);

Document query = new Document();
List<StockTakingItem> stockItems = collection.find(query, StockTakingItem.class).into(new ArrayList<StockTakingItem>());
```

Though if I display the values then:

For **MongoCollection collection** I got this (so the document with proper values is there).

```
{ "_id" : "asdfasdfasdf", "Description" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa description ", "Note" : "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn Another note " }
```

But my StockTakingItem has null values in it (except for an **id**)

```
StockTakingItem:id: 'asdfasdfasdf', Description: 'null', Note: 'null
```

EDIT:

StockTakingItem class:

```
public class StockTakingItem {

   @BsonId
   String _id;

   String _description;

   String _note;

   [getters and setters]
}
```

This code for inserting is working:

```
var collection = _mongoDataBase.getCollection(collectionName);
collection.insertOne(docToInsert);
```

Why are there null values and how can I do it properly so it works as intended?

Comment: Why are your fields named `_description` instead of `description`?

Comment: C# syntax habit

Comment: Your `_id` field is recognized as the ID because you explicitly annotated it. Otherwise, you don't *seem* to have a property named `Description` or `Note`; in both Java and MongoDB practice, those are `description` and `note`. If you want to use the capitalized versions, you may need to annotate the properties or accessors.

Comment: I actually used annotations earlier (@BsonProperty(value = "Note")) and there's no difference. It still doesn't work with, or without it. And inserting gives the same result anyway = works.